# How to split funds in single send transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

**Scenario:**

- Alice Account = 2 ETH
- Admin Account = 0 ETH
- Bob Account = 0 ETH

Alice wants to send 1 ETH to Bob using my application. Application will charge 0.01 ETH as it's commission and will be added to total transaction fee

*Total Fee* = Application Fee (0.01) + Network Fee (gas limit * gas price)

Suppose Network fee is calculated to 0.001008 ETH.

*Total payable amount* = **1.011008 ETH** (1 + 0.01 + 0.001008)

After successful transaction following should be the account details

- Alice Account = 0.988992 ETH
- Admin Account = 0.01 ETH
- Bob Account = 1 ETH

where as 0.001008 ETH will be paid to miners

**Query:**

Q1. How can I build an application where a funds of a single send transaction can be sent to two different addresses (Bob's address and Admin's address)?

Q2. Is it possible to build such an application without using smart contracts?

Comment: You might need a fixed-point math library in order to do this. See [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math) and this thread: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An smart contract would need to be involved in the process.
It would basically be transferred the funds and send them to different accounts as specified within its logic.

Here's a very quick example I've put together for you:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Forwarder {

    address admin;
    uint fee = 10;

    constructor() public {

        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    function splitFunds(address _b) public payable {

        admin.transfer(msg.value * fee / 100);
        _b.transfer(msg.value - (msg.value * fee / 100));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: so fee equal 10 means 10 percent? or 1 percent?